Listview seems not to respond to adapter changes after accessing Fragment by back button
I am developing an android app with a few fragments.
activity_main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

content_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I also have a nav_graph.xml, but when I post it this question is classified as spam :)
I navigate like this
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_global_showIngredientListFragment);

or this:
ShowDrinkListFragmentDirections.ActionDrinkListToEditDrink action =
                        ShowDrinkListFragmentDirections.actionDrinkListToEditDrink();
                action.setDrinkDBId(0);
                Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action);

I initialize the whole Fragment in onCreateView(...)
I now have the problem that if I reach a Fragement containing mainly a ListView by the back button of the device, the changes to the content of the ListView by inserting and removing views to the adapter that is set to it, are not displayed. If I instead navigate to it by the way shown above, everything is handled as i want it to. I did log some lifecycle methods on the Fragment that were called when reaching it on the two described ways. They are identical and seem reasonable. On leaving the fragment: onPause, onStop, onDestroyview. When navigation back (same for clicking navigation or back button): onCreateView onViewCreated, onStart, onResume.
I can't explain why I see the changes happening in the UI when navigating there by the way shown above, but not by clicking the back button, even though the same methods are called where the manipiulation on the customMade Adapter happen.

Could solve the issue by moving the manipulation of the ListView to
onViewStateRestored(...). Still don't know why this is only necessary by getting to the view by the back-button.
